# Selenium Drop Down Menu : where is the valid locator?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

my problem is as follows:

i want to select from a dropdown menu.

The html gives this:

```
<select class="js-order-type-buysell order-buysell-selector" style="opacity: 0" data-width="100%" tabindex="null">
                                            <option selected="selected">Bitte wählen...</option>
                                            <option value="buy">Kauf</option>
                                            <option value="sell">Verkauf</option>
                                        </select>
```

this also is embedded in a div

```
<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select js-order-type-buysell order-buysell-selector bs3" style="width: 100%;">
```

my code is as follows

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

username = "*******"
password = "*******"

url = "https://www.wikifolio.com/dynamic/de/de/login/login?ReturnUrl=/de/de/home&_=1632037782306"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'\Users\Benjamin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name("Username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button").click()

driver.get("https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/meine-wikifolios/trade/wf00wiking")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__abort, .c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__change"))).click()



wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-description='AKER CARB.CAPT.AS NK1']"))).click()

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="trading-modal-root"]')
Select(e).select_by_value('selected').click()
```

So especially i am asking for a solution of this last part:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="trading-modal-root"]')
Select(e).select_by_value('selected').click()
```

is there any way to do this, given what i have?

When i run this code, then this Error message appears:

```
UnexpectedTagNameException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-242d18138a79> in <module>
     30 
     31 e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="trading-modal-root"]')
---> 32 Select(e).select_by_value('selected').click()
     33 
     34 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py in __init__(self, webelement)
     37             raise UnexpectedTagNameException(
     38                 "Select only works on <select> elements, not on <%s>" %
---> 39                 webelement.tag_name)
     40         self._el = webelement
     41         multi = self._el.get_attribute("multiple")

UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>
```

The solution i have from this site: https://intellipaat.com/community/4266/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-option-value-with-selenium-python

the conversation there goes as follows:

```
I need to select an element from a drop-down menu.

For example:

<select id="fruits01" class="select" name="fruits">

  <option value="0">Choose your fruits:</option>

  <option value="1">Banana</option>

  <option value="2">Mango</option>

</select>

First I have to click on it. I do this:

inputElementFruits = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[id='fruits']").click()

After that I have to select the good element, let us say Mango.

I tried to do it with inputElementFruits.send_keys(...) but it did not work.
```

with the answer

```
In my opinion, unless your click is firing some kind of ajax call to populate your list, you don't actually need to execute the click. 

Select the element and enumerate the options, selecting the option(s) you want. For example,

from selenium import webdriver

b = webdriver.Firefox()

b.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='element_name']/option[text()='option_text']").click()

For more information please go through the following tutorial to get more info about Selenium:
```

and

```
Selenium presents a convenient Select class to work with select -> option constructs:

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('fruits01'))

# select by visible text

select.select_by_visible_text('Banana')

# select by value 

select.select_by_value('1')
```

so i tried to addapt that solution to my code.

is it possible, that i first need to select the "visible" div part of dropdown menu, before i can select on of the selectors from the  part of the html?

Thanks folks, i appreciate any help
Benjamin

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do by `e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="trading-modal-root"]')
Select(e).select_by_value('selected').click()`?

Comment: The modal dialog is opened, what do you want to do now? BTW I fixed the `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__abort, .c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__change"))).click()
` locator on my previous answer :) It is unique and short while this is not unique and too long...

Comment: well to be honest, me neither, this was just a solution i got from that site: https://intellipaat.com/community/4266/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-option-value-with-selenium-python

Comment: Error 1020 Ray ID: 6915334b3c8c3a71 • 2021-09-19 19:25:30 UTC
Access denied
What happened?
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

Comment: Can you describe here?

Comment: which website? Wikifolio or the intellipaat.com? :)

Comment: The intellipaat.com

Comment: i will edit my question with an explaination

Comment: I see. So, what drop-down menu do you want to open and what value to select in that modal dialog?

Comment: so there is only one dropdown menu, its the one, on which chrome gives me the xpath //*[@id="trading-modal-root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/select  --> from that menu i want to select either the value "buy" or the value "sell" how its visible in the given html in the upper part of my question

Comment: i edited my question and added the div element in which the <select> is embedded. I think it might be that  first I need to select the "visible" div part of dropdown menu, before i can select on of the selectors from the <select> part of the html?

Comment: No, "select" element having "select" tag name. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening the modal dialog with

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-description='AKER CARB.CAPT.AS NK1']"))).click()
```

You can do the following:
To select the quota:

```py
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='trading-modal-root' and(contains(@style,'block'))]//select[@class='js-order-type-select order-type-selector']")))
select1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='trading-modal-root' and(contains(@style,'block'))]//select[@class='js-order-type-select order-type-selector']"))

# select by value "limit"
select1.select_by_value('limit')
#or "quote"
select1.select_by_value('quote')
#or "stop"
select1.select_by_value('stop')

#to select purchase or sale action:
select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='trading-modal-root' and(contains(@style,'block'))]//select[@class='js-order-type-buysell order-buysell-selector']"))

# select by value "buy"
select2.select_by_value('buy')
#or "sell"
select2.select_by_value('sell')
```